# Create separate file for Sidebar to be stored in and Easily edited

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I have had a hard time finding a solution to this problem. I have been searching for the past 3 days and I have not found any results, so I came here to ask. I want to keep my sidebar in a separate file so it saves up some space in my index.html and is eligible for use in other pages as well. This is what I want in my sidebar: (NOTE: I have used Bootstrap's UI "Bootflat")

```
<h1 align="center">Calendar</h1>
 <div class="row" align="center">
    <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
        <div class="calendar" align="center">
            <div class="years clearfix">
                <div class="unit prev"><em></em></div>
                <div class="monyear">DECEMBER 2015</div>
                <div class="unit next"><em></em></div>
            </div>
            <div class="days">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="unit linkcur">SU</div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur">MO</div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur">TU</div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur">WE</div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur">TH</div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur">FR</div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur">SA</div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>29</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>30</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>1</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>2</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>3</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>4</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>5</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>6</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>7</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>8</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>9</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>10</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>11</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>12</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>13</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>14</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>15</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>16</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>17</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>18</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>19</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>20</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>21</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>22</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>23</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>24</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>25</b></div>
                    <div class="row tooltip-demo"><div class="unit active linkcur" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Launch Day"><b>26</b></div></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>27</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>28</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>29</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>30</b></div>
                    <div class="unit linkcur"><b>31</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>1</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>2</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>3</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>4</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>5</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>6</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>7</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>8</b></div>
                    <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>9</b></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
<hr>
```

As you can see it takes a lot of space. I want this piece of Code in a separate file so that I can easily connect it to my other pages and easily edit it. Please help!


**EDIT:**
The PHP file is Successful but It doesn't seem to show up in the pages.

The result in the PHP page:
[The Result in PHP Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMHs3.jpg)

What I get in the Homepage=
[What I get in the Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54XPf.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use PHP, all you have to do is create a new html file, put your code in there and save it with the extension `.php`. Then all you have to do is put

```
<?php include("Sidebar.php"); ?>
```

wherever you want the sidebar.

#### Update:

Save this file as `Sidebar.php`. Then in all your html pages that have that code you can rename the extension to `.php` and place the above code instead of the sidebar, so you only have to make changes in one file to update the entire site where it is included.

```
<h1 align="center">Calendar</h1>
<div class="row" align="center">
<div class="col-md-4" align="center">
    <div class="calendar" align="center">
        <div class="years clearfix">
            <div class="unit prev"><em></em></div>
            <div class="monyear">DECEMBER 2015</div>
            <div class="unit next"><em></em></div>
        </div>
        <div class="days">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="unit linkcur">SU</div>
                <div class="unit linkcur">MO</div>
                <div class="unit linkcur">TU</div>
                <div class="unit linkcur">WE</div>
                <div class="unit linkcur">TH</div>
                <div class="unit linkcur">FR</div>
                <div class="unit linkcur">SA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>29</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>30</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>1</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>2</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>3</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>4</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>5</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>6</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>7</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>8</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>9</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>10</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>11</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>12</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>13</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>14</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>15</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>16</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>17</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>18</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>19</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>20</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>21</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>22</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>23</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>24</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>25</b></div>
                <div class="row tooltip-demo"><div class="unit active linkcur" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Launch Day"><b>26</b></div></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>27</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>28</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>29</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>30</b></div>
                <div class="unit linkcur"><b>31</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>1</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>2</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>3</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>4</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>5</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>6</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>7</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>8</b></div>
                <div class="unit older linkcur"><b>9</b></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Or is it possible that it can be used in form of Javascript?

Comment: With JavaScript you could create a div named something like Dynamic and leave it empty in place of all that code. Then create a JavaScript file that will append all that code to the Dynamic div. Then you just have to include the JavaScript file on all the html pages that have that code

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: It really doesn't work. As I am putting this in a Sidebar, Maybe that is causing the problem or I am missing Something?

Comment: The web host must also have php installed. I use Azure which has it installed already. You may have to contact your web host for help on installing it. For the JavaScript way you'll have to search how to create a dynamic div as I'm still learning it and the code where i created one is not accessible

Comment: Thanks for the Help Everyone!

Comment: I have reworded this answer to try to make it clearer. It *was* all one sentence, which was hard to read. However, this is a great method, and it's the one I have been using on a client's site for some time. +1